# Array of character pointer declaration looks different in the below code

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compilation

I have seen a pointer of strings array defined as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char * testArray[sizeof(unsigned int) * 8][2]=
{

   [0] = {"Test", "Index 0"},
   [1] = {"Test", "Index 1 "},
   [2] = {"Test", "Index 2"},
   [3] = {"Test", "Index 3"},
   [4] = {"Test", "Index 4"},
   [5] = {"Test", "Index 5"},
};
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 6; i++)
        printf("%s\n",testArray[i][1]); //Prints Index 0-5

for (i = 0 ; i< 6; i++)
        printf("%s\n",testArray[i][0]); //Prints Test
}
```

I am not familiar with this way of array declaration and indexing. Can some one explain how this indexing and code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it is, it's doing nothing, it's the same as having:

```
{"Test", "Index 0"},
{"Test", "Index 1"},
{"Test", "Index 2"},
{"Test", "Index 3"},
{"Test", "Index 4"},
{"Test", "Index 5"},
```

But you can use those indexes to order the rows in the initialization, for instance:

```
[5] = {"Test", "Index 0"},
[1] = {"Test", "Index 1"},
[0] = {"Test", "Index 2"},
[3] = {"Test", "Index 3"},
[4] = {"Test", "Index 4"},
[2] = {"Test", "Index 5"},
```

Here there is a reordering of the array, what would normally be index 0 will be index 5, index 2 will be index 0, and index 5 will be index 2.

The expression

```
char *testArray[sizeof(unsigned int) * 8][2]
```

Declares a bi-dimensional array of pointers to char with 8 times the size of an `unsigned int` of rows and 2 columns, as in most systems an `int` has 4 bytes in size you will end up with a bi-dimensional array with 32 rows and 2 columns.

To each pointer can be assigned a char array, meaning that each one of the 32 rows can have 2 char arrays, one for each column.

You have a 2D array that can hold 32 x 2 char arrays, that's too much for what you need given the assignments.

You can either declare the first dimension empty and it will be deduced by the compiler:

```
char *testArray[][2]= ...
```

Or explicitly give it the dimension you need, which in this case is 6:

```
char *testArray[6][2]= ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[N]` in `[N] = {"Test", "Index N"}` is used to address/access the specific row level of the two dimensional pointer to `char` array `testArray`.

For example:

```
char * testArray[6][2]=
{
   [5] = {"Test1", "Index 5"},
   [4] = {"Test2", "Index 4"},
   [3] = {"Test3", "Index 3"},
   [2] = {"Test4", "Index 2"},
   [1] = {"Test5", "Index 1"},
   [0] = {"Test6", "Index 0"},
};
```

will print:

```
Index 0
Index 1
Index 2
Index 3
Index 4
Index 5
Test6
Test5
Test4
Test3
Test2
Test1
```

The difference is that the order of the specific initializations doesn't matter. You can rearrange them however you like it, it will be still equivalent to:

```
char * testArray[6][2] =
{
   {"Test6", "Index 0"},
   {"Test5", "Index 1"},
   {"Test4", "Index 2"},
   {"Test3", "Index 3"},
   {"Test2", "Index 4"},
   {"Test1", "Index 5"},
};
```

---

Side Notes:

- You should define `testArray` as `const char * testArray`, so that you can't get into undefined behavior by any unintentional write attempt as all assigned pointers point to string literals, which can´t be modified.
- Why are you using `[sizeof(unsigned int) * 8]` to determine the rows? You just need `6` rows. Use `const char * testArray[6][2]` instead.